# Carrito de compras problema con agg productos

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un carrito de compras pero no se como crear una condición para cuando el producto no esta agg lo agregue y cuando ya lo tenga no lo agg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** No está muy bien especificado el problema pero bueno, tenes que llamar por medio de un evento onClick la función add_to_cart, tenes
que pasarle como parámetro el id del producto (agg me imagino que es agregado)**

```
const shopping_cart = [1,2,3];

const add_to_cart = (product_id) => {
    if(!shopping_cart[product_id]){
      shopping_cart.push(product_id)
    }
  console.log(shopping_cart)

}
```

Comment: Disculpa si no puse el codigo de ejemplo lo que pasa es que todavia me enrollo mucho con el editor de codigo de esta pagina